# AnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName to return whether the state ends in a certain word

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am new to 2d animation in unity and wanted to write a script that determines the direction my character is facing based on what animation is playing. My animations are all called something like `idleL` or `walkingL`. 
At the moment I looping through all of my animations to determine which way the character is facing with AnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName.
Would it be possible to just determine if the animation ends in the characters L, R, U or D using this function?

Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, why would you determine the orientation based on animation rather than on movement itself?

Comment: @Armin I know how to do it though movement and I wanted to see if I could do it through the animations. I am not working on a project at the moment and was curious to see how its done. You never know, it might come in handy one day.

Comment: Ah I see, well unless unity blesses us with a GetName() on the animator state info, it's gonna remain rather difficult

Comment: We can only hope. Thanks anyway @Armin

Comment: On runtime the animator uses only **Hashes**! There is [no way](https://forum.unity.com/threads/current-animator-state-name.331803/) to directly get the name of an animator state on runtime. That's why there is also only `IsName` since it hashes the given name and checks if it matches the states hash ...

Answer (score -1):

You can acces the clip name by using [GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html). You can see how its done in the example in the docs.

```
    //Get them_Animator, which you attach to the GameObject you intend to animate.
    m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    //Fetch the current Animation clip information for the base layer
    m_CurrentClipInfo = this.m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
    //Access the Animation clip name
    m_ClipName = m_CurrentClipInfo[0].clip.name;
```

Comment: The clip name might be different from the state name though ...

Comment: True just went of the "My animations are all called" and "looping through all of my animations" and went into problem solving, since they kept mentioning animations and not states. But missed the main question.